# How do you disable a button in xcode 8 from inside another button?

Tags: xcode8

How do you disable a button in xcode 8 from inside another button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you set outlet or not :).Use btn.isEnabled = false on tapping other button. YES/NO don't work if you are coding in swift. From ios 10 enabled or other bool getter method we need to add 'is' for prefix of object. example isHidden.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error I found out that you actually need to create an outlet for the button as well as the action , then you can use the outlet name with .isEnabled, thanks for your help :)

Comment: So can you please give accepted and up vote for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `myBtn.enabled = NO`
on click event of other button.